# Creating users in text or json file and use it to the login to the python web

Tags: python, html, web, flask, authentication

I've made simple web. This is the method which I use to basic login to the web:

```
@app.route('/signin/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def signin_page():
    error = None
    try:
        if request.method == "POST":
            attempted_email= request.form['email']
            attempted_password = request.form['password']

            flash(attempted_email)
            flash(attempted_password)

            if attempted_email == "admin@gmail.com" and attempted_password == "admin":
                return redirect(url_for('homepage'))
            else:
                error = "Invalid credentials. Try again."

    except Exception as e:
        flash(e)
        return render_template("signin.html", error = error)
```

How can I modify that code if I want to take the users data from txt or json file (I want to make it using basic editor txt), which contains information about users (email, password, etc.) ?
How can I compare typed string in login form with content of the file ?

Answer (score 1):

I assume you have a text file with the content `username:password`. You can now do something like:

```
PW_FILE = 'path/to/file/'

def check_credentials(username: str, password: str) -> bool:
    # load content of file
    with open(PW_FILE) as fh:
        content = fh.read().strip('\n')  # and remove newlines
    credentials = content.split(':', 1)  # get credentials as list `[username, password]`
    return credentials == [username, password]


@app.route('/signin/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def signin_page():
    ...
        if check_credentials(attempted_email, attempted_password):
            return redirect(url_for('homepage'))
        else:
            error = "Invalid credentials. Try again." 
    ...
```

---

In general, you should not catch an unspecific exception, as you might swallow some unexpected behaviour. I am not familiar with the framework you are using, but I would suggest changing your error handling to be more specific, something like

```
@app.route('/signin/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def signin_page():
    error = None
    if request.method == "POST":
        try:
            attempted_email= request.form['email']
            attempted_password = request.form['password']
        except KeyError:
            error = "Missing form data"
        else:
            if check_credentials(attempted_email, attempted_password):
               return redirect(url_for('homepage'))
            else:
                error = "Invalid credentials. Try again."
        return render_template("signin.html", error = error)
```